# Onchange within a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, mediawiki

I am making a JavaScript solution related to MediaWiki, but what it is for is not really needed information, so I will leave it there. I have the following function:

```
wgAjaxLicensePreview=true;
function getLicensePreview(num) {
    console.log('glp num', num);
    window.licenseSelectorCheck = function () {
        var selector = document.getElementById("license" + num);
        var selection = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selector.selectedIndex > 0) {
            if (selection == "") {
                // Option disabled, but browser is broken and doesn't respect this
                selector.selectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        // We might show a preview
        wgUploadLicenseObj.fetchPreview(selection);
    };
    var wpLicense = document.getElementById('license' + num);
    console.log('glp wpLicense', wpLicense);

    if (mw.config.get('wgAjaxLicensePreview') && wpLicense) {
        // License selector check
        wpLicense.onchange = licenseSelectorCheck;

        // License selector table row
        var wpLicenseRow = wpLicense.parentNode.parentNode;
        var wpLicenseTbody = wpLicenseRow.parentNode;

        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        row.appendChild(td);
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.id = 'mw-license-preview' + num;
        row.appendChild(td);

        wpLicenseTbody.insertBefore(row, wpLicenseRow.nextSibling);
        console.log('glp row', row);
    }

    window.wgUploadLicenseObj = {

        'responseCache': {
            '': ''
        },

        'fetchPreview': function (license) {
            if (!mw.config.get('wgAjaxLicensePreview'))
                return;
            for (cached in this.responseCache) {
                console.log('glp fp responseCache', this.responseCache);
                if (cached == license) {
                    this.showPreview(this.responseCache[license]);
                    return;
                }
            }
            $('#license' + num).injectSpinner('license' + num);

            var title = document.getElementById('imagename' + num).value;
            if (!title)
                title = 'File:Sample.jpg';

            var url = mw.util.wikiScript('api')
                 + '?action=parse&text={{' + encodeURIComponent(license) + '}}'
                 + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title)
                 + '&prop=text&pst&format=json';

            var req = sajax_init_object();
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    console.log('glp fp response', req.responseText);
                    wgUploadLicenseObj.processResult(eval('(' + req.responseText + ')'), license);
                }
            };
            req.open('GET', url, true);
            req.send('');

        },

        'processResult': function (result, license) {
            $.removeSpinner('license' + num);
            this.responseCache[license] = result['parse']['text']['*'];
            console.log('glp pr result license', result, license);
            this.showPreview(this.responseCache[license]);
        },

        'showPreview': function (preview) {
            var previewPanel = document.getElementById('mw-license-preview' + num);
            console.log('glp sp', previewPanel, preview, previewPanel.innerHTML == preview);
            if (previewPanel.innerHTML != preview)
                previewPanel.innerHTML = preview;
        }

    };
}
```

The issue with that, is the loop I have

```
  var limit = this.max < this.fileCount ? this.max : this.fileCount;
    console.log('glp', this.max, this.fileCount);
    for (i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
    console.log('glp i', i);
    getLicensePreview(i);
    }
```

Does not iterate correctly for part of it, I have narrowed the issue down to, `wpLicense.onchange = licenseSelectorCheck;` which is rewriting the event handler to only check the last <kbd>num</kbd>.

Comment: Not related to the problem: `selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;` can be simplified to just `selector.value`

Comment: Is there a reason you're assigning the function to `window.licenseSelectorCheck`? You're reassigning that global variable each time you call the function.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I will change that - simplifying is always good! And I still have alot to learn, so I was actual unaware of an issue that can cause, do you have any recommendations to fix it?

Comment: I'm still reading and trying to understand the code....

Comment: These window vars cannot work...you are overwriting them each time in the loop

Comment: That's right. At the end of the loop, `window.wgUploadLicenseObj` will just be whatever you set on the last iteration.

Comment: @Barmar Alright. Thanks, if you need me to clarify anything else, I most certainly will I just tried to minimize what I put here, to not give unneeded information.
 Any recommendations then? I am not the best with this, but still learning! Help is appreciated.

Comment: What you probably need to do is create that object locally inside the `licenseSelectorCheck` function, not use a global variable.

Comment: Or define it one time as a prototype or class, and then make an instance in the `licenseSelectorCheck` function.

Comment: The code is kind of complicated, so it's hard to tell precisely what you need to do. I also don't know MediaWiki, so I don't know how it interacts with that.

Comment: The fact that it uses mediawiki I believe is unneeded, a way for the loop to work is more-what this question is.

Comment: @Barmar As for the making it local rather then global, do you have a way for me to do this? I am still learning a lot, and it gets tricky for me when it comes to doing this type of stuff sometimes.

Comment: `var wgUploadLicense = { ... }; wguploadLicense.fetchPreview(selection);`

Comment: Although now that I look at it some more, it doesn't seem like the code in that object refers much to local variables. It's not clear why it needs to be inside the function.

Comment: @Barmar well, whatever the reason, it now works 100% After 12 hours you help me in 5 minutes! Thanks! You can submit an answer and I will accept it if you want.

Comment: lol, I wasn't even sure I was right. Feel free to post what you actually coded.

Comment: @Barmar I posted the solution thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from Barmar, I was able to solve this by making the `wgUploadLicenseObj` variable local rather then global `window.wgUploadLicenseObj`.
My final function ended up being:

```
wgAjaxLicensePreview=true;
function getLicensePreview(num) {
    window.licenseSelectorCheck = function () {
        var selector = document.getElementById("license" + num);
        var selection = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selector.selectedIndex > 0) {
            if (selection == "") {
                // Option disabled, but browser is broken and doesn't respect this
                selector.selectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        var wgUploadLicenseObj = {

        'responseCache': {
            '': ''
        },

        'fetchPreview': function (license) {
            if (!mw.config.get('wgAjaxLicensePreview'))
                return;
            for (cached in this.responseCache) {
                if (cached == license) {
                    this.showPreview(this.responseCache[license]);
                    return;
                }
            }
            $('#license' + num).injectSpinner('license' + num);

            var title = document.getElementById('imagename' + num).value;
            if (!title)
                title = 'File:Sample.jpg';

            var url = mw.util.wikiScript('api')
                 + '?action=parse&text={{' + encodeURIComponent(license) + '}}'
                 + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title)
                 + '&prop=text&pst&format=json';

            var req = sajax_init_object();
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    wgUploadLicenseObj.processResult(eval('(' + req.responseText + ')'), license);
                }
            };
            req.open('GET', url, true);
            req.send('');

        },

        'processResult': function (result, license) {
            $.removeSpinner('license' + num);
            this.responseCache[license] = result['parse']['text']['*'];
            this.showPreview(this.responseCache[license]);
        },

        'showPreview': function (preview) {
            var previewPanel = document.getElementById('mw-license-preview' + num);
            if (previewPanel.innerHTML != preview)
                previewPanel.innerHTML = preview;
        }

    };
        // We might show a preview
        wgUploadLicenseObj.fetchPreview(selection);
    };
    var wpLicense = document.getElementById('license' + num);

    if (mw.config.get('wgAjaxLicensePreview') && wpLicense) {
        // License selector check
        wpLicense.onchange = licenseSelectorCheck;

        // License selector table row
        var wpLicenseRow = wpLicense.parentNode.parentNode;
        var wpLicenseTbody = wpLicenseRow.parentNode;

        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        row.appendChild(td);
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.id = 'mw-license-preview' + num;
        row.appendChild(td);

        wpLicenseTbody.insertBefore(row, wpLicenseRow.nextSibling);
    }
}
```